# How is bilinear interpolation implemented in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, remap, bilinear-interpolation

I was going through **OpenCV** **remap()** implementation. I am particularly interested in bilinear interpolation. I am bit overwhelmed with the complexity of the implementation. I couldn't find any documentation which explains the implementation.

Where can I find documentation on **OpenCV** **remap()** implementation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you like to understand the implementation, or it's complexity ? :P  Better ask for this on [their QA](http://answers.opencv.org/questions/)

Comment: @sop I want to implement it in hardware. Thanks, I will raise the question there.

Comment: Do you know about [OpenVX](https://www.khronos.org/openvx/) ?

Comment: @sop No. I just looked into it. It seems there is no ASIC / FPGA implementation as such as. Most of them are GPU based.

Comment: Can someone please answer this?